# value in a recursive loop

Tags: erlang

In a recursive loop, I would like to change the value of a variable:

```
loop(N) when N > ... ->
N;
loop(N) ->
case ... of
  N+1
  ...
end,
...
case ... of
  N-1
  ...
end,
...
loop(N).
```

How to "pass" the new value of N ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you can't change the value of `N` once assigned, you need to call `loop` with the new value:

```
loop(N) ->
    loop(N+1).
```

Alternatively, create a temporary variable to hold its new value before passing it into the recursive `loop` invocation.

```
loop(N) ->
    NewN = N+1,
    loop(NewN).
```

If this results in a lot of repetition in your code, you might want to separate the looping construct from the logic which produces the new value of N:

```
loop(N) ->
    NewN = logic(N),
    loop(NewN).

logic(N) ->
    N+1.
```

Comment: Ok but I have a classical problem with the case. I cannot use if because the guard functions are limited. I am obliged to use case but only one clause has an interest. Then I have "unsafe" messages !

Comment: `case` is an expression (everything is an expression in Erlang) so it returns value. You can bind this to NewN which you use in the recursive call. Something like `NewN = case ... end, loop(NewN).` This will remove the unsafe errors.

Comment: Ok but I am obliged to manage the second clause of the case ! B = case X of one -> 1;_other->[] end      what I want is: if X == one -> B=1 end

Comment: Defining `B` as `1` if and only if `(X==one)` and NOT defining `B` at all in all other cases does not make sense to me.

Comment: Yes, seeing you are always going `B` to use you must give it a value.

Comment: because you don't know the context ! B is already defined. According to a condition B can be incremented. According to another one B can be decremented. My example (X===one) was just theoretical.

Answer (score 4):

You simply call the function with a new value:

```
$ cat fac.erl
-module(fac).
-export([fac/1]).

fac(0) -> 1;
fac(N) when N > 0 -> N*fac(N-1).

$ erl
Erlang R13B03 (erts-5.7.4) [source] [64-bit] [smp:8:8] [rq:8] [async-threads:0] [hipe] [kernel-poll:false]

Eshell V5.7.4  (abort with ^G)
1> c(fac).
{ok,fac}
2> fac:fac(10).
3628800
3> q().
ok
4> $
```

Shamelessly stolen from: http://learnyousomeerlang.com/recursion#hello-recursion