# f(var) only works in a shell session?

Tags: erlang

I'm needing to reset some variables in a loop in order to assign the new values (like finding the index of a substring) i cannot reuse the same var so i must unset it and as far as i know the f(var) only works in a shell?

so is there no way to do this in a script?

Comment: How about an iterative function where you can pass anything you want, from within the function body, into the function's state/variables in an iterative call.

Comment: The easiest solution is of course just to use a new variable! :-)

Comment: See also [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4861468/113848) and [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4777152/113848).

Answer (score 8):

`f()` is a shell-only command.

Erlang as a language uses immutable variables, and as such does not allow the resetting of variables within the code itself. The recommendation is to get comfortable with recursion, list comprehensions, mapping, or folding in order to accomplish "loops" which don't exist in the procedural sense in Erlang.

If you *must* rely on variable state, the closest thing you get to mutable variables is the process dictionary: `get/1` and `put/2`. These are generally discouraged unless there is a good reason for using them.